# SimpleCursorAdapter is being difficult to use

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have been stuck at one point from long time, i.e with the use of

```
 SimpleCursorAdapter
```

as it fails while returning the correct value. I have seen similar many post in SO itself, saying that I should add _id column in the cursor database query, rather I should do

```
 db.rawQuery(String,String)
```

My code in the onCreate(..) is

```
HospitalData = new Database(this);
HospitalData.open();
Cursor c = HospitalData.getAllRows_Patient_Db();
startManagingCursor(c);
c.moveToFirst();

//HERE SOME LOOP IS NEEDED FOR TRAVERSING AND PUTTING IN THE LISTVIEW
while(c.isAfterLast() == false)
{
    String[] columns = new String[] { c.getString(1), c.getString(2) };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.room_number_db, R.id.pt_initial_db };
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.patient_db, c,columns,to);
    c.moveToNext();
}
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

And previously my database accessing code was as follows

```
 public Cursor getAllRows_Patient_Db() 
{               
    return db.query(DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_ROOM_NUMBER,                             
                                                        KEY_PATIENT_INITIAL
            }, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);
}
```

where KEY_ROWID  is defined as follows

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
```

And the error with this is

```
07-04 22:10:23.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16795): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '90' does not exist
07-04 22:10:23.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16795):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
07-04 22:10:23.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16795):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:312)
```

Here column 90 is not the column id but according to my database is the data stored in cursor.getString(1), but I think here it is trying to search cursor.getString(0) which is the row id.

Later I changed my code as follows

```
public Cursor getAllRows_Patient_Db() 
{
  String db_sel = "SELECT id as _id, KEY_ROOM_NUMBER" +
    ",KEY_PATIENT_INITIAL FROM DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE";

    return db.rawQuery(db_sel,null);
}
```

But still I am getting error, this time error is different

```
07-04 21:36:12.510: ERROR/global(9861): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.

 07-04 21:36:12.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-04 21:36:12.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9861): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pro/com.pro.CopyOfFirstScreen}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE: , while compiling: SELECT id as _id, KEY_ROOM_NUMBER,KEY_PATIENT_INITIAL FROM DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE

 07-04 21:36:12.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9861): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE: , while compiling: SELECT id as _id, KEY_ROOM_NUMBER,KEY_PATIENT_INITIAL FROM DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE
```

I am stuck with it from very long time, please help!!

EDIT : Okay now with you guys help my query statement is correct and thanks for that, I am sorry I am not good in understanding the syntax for database query but I am trying to learn

The working query after changes is

```
String db_sel = "SELECT _id as _id, room_number" +",patient_initial FROM " + DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE;
```

Actually I had to change the declared String with the key values

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_ROOM_NUMBER = "room_number";
public static final String KEY_PATIENT_INITIAL = "patient_initial";
```

But now I see another problem that is not from the query statement but the way I am accessing or using the simplecursorAdapter

[image: DB Table]

As you can see that my table has 2 rows and 3 columns, Now I want to fetch the data from column 2 and column 3 and put it in my listview. 
But after the fix from the query I am getting another error

Originally it was

```
   String[] columns = new String[] {c.getString(1), c.getString(2) };
        int[] to = new int[] {  R.id.room_number_db, R.id.pt_initial_db };
     adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.patient_db, c,columns,to);
     c.moveToNext();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

And the error was

```
  07-05 21:32:29.228: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '90' does not exist
  07-05 21:32:29.228: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
  07-05 21:32:29.228: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:312)
```

android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:312)

As you can see it is trying to access the data of first column inspite of accessing the row

After that I made changes in my code

```
     int x = 0;         
     String[] columns = new String[] { c.getString(0),c.getString(1), c.getString(2) };
        int[] to = new int[] { x, R.id.room_number_db, R.id.pt_initial_db };
     adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.patient_db, c,columns,to);
     c.moveToNext();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This was only a guess in order to find out how differently SimpleCursorAdapter works compared to a normal cursor and the error I get is

```
 07-05 21:34:47.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1966): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '1' does not exist
 07-05 21:34:47.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
```

I know this question is becoming too long :-( do u suggest me to remove some code from here.

Comment: This error is often raised if Android cannot find the database file. Is there a reason you're not using the canonical DatabaseHelper?

Comment: I have used DatabaseHelper for creating my database, may be my question was not clear before. I have added the error which I was getting before, please have a look to it and kindly guide me if possibe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed, the main thing is that I should make sure I always query for the _id with each query to the database, but if I do it with cursor.getString(someIndex) then this gets misleaded as the adapter in my case is taking the content of first column as the rowid and is trying to search the row.

Nether doing rawQuery(),or using "Select _id as _id" stuffs are mandatory. these things are sometime misleading as I felt.

So keeping things simple below is the code.
Database code

```
 public Cursor getAllRows_Patient_Db() 
{               
    return db.query(DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID, 
            KEY_ROOM_NUMBER,
            KEY_PATIENT_INITIAL
            }, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);
}
```

Activity Code

```
    HospitalData = new Database(this);
    HospitalData.open();
    Cursor c = HospitalData.getAllRows_Patient_Db();


    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] columns = new String[] {HospitalData.KEY_ROOM_NUMBER,HospitalData.KEY_PATIENT_INITIAL };
     int[] to = new int[] {  R.id.room_number_db, R.id.pt_initial_db };
     adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.patient_db, c,columns,to);
     c.moveToNext();
     setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you read this part of error stack:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE:
```

?
You just have no such table in database. It's not CursorAdapter problem.
Your loop seems completely pointless - just read some java handbook.
Ok, lets start to list some problems in your code:

```
String[] columns = new String[] { c.getString(1), c.getString(2) };
```

`columns[]` should contain columns **names** not values...
In your `while{}` loop you are creating dozens(?) of SimpleCursorAdapters while only the last on is passed.
This part of code:

```
String db_sel = "SELECT id as _id, KEY_ROOM_NUMBER" +
    ",KEY_PATIENT_INITIAL FROM DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE";
```

is obviously wrong. I assume that you have something like

```
private static String DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE = "patient";
```

so just use those constants:

```
String db_sel = "select id as _id, +"KEY_ROOM_NUMBER+", "+ KEY_PATIENT_INITIAL +" from "+DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE;
```

Replace that:

```
 String[] columns = new String[] { c.getString(0),c.getString(1), c.getString(2) };
    int[] to = new int[] { x, R.id.room_number_db, R.id.pt_initial_db };
```

With that:

```
 String[] columns = new String[] { c.getColumnName(1), c.getColumnName(2) };
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.room_number_db, R.id.pt_initial_db };
```

Comment: This error I am getting only after making change in the public Cursor getAllRows_Patient_Db() 
{
  String db_sel = "SELECT id as _id, KEY_ROOM_NUMBER" +
    ",KEY_PATIENT_INITIAL FROM DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE";

    return db.rawQuery(db_sel,null);
} with previous code it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I mean o say that the table gets generated perfectly

Comment: Please see my edit code I have added the error which I was getting before where looks like It was trying to search the rowid and was crashing for that.

Comment: +1 for your help, I am weak in understanding the query statement, tough I am trying hard to understand them, and that that error is fixed but my issue with SimpleCursorAdapter is not yet fixed. I have added my detailed scenario. Please let me know where I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Solution is above. Please read a book about programming you have troubles with basics.

Comment: Dear Piotpro : to tell you this was my code before, I had changed it and was just testing and I am getting error with this so I made changes. And thanks for such a kind help.

Comment: I don't understand why people start answering without reading the question first and start giving such a rude suggestion

Comment: Dear Shaista - you have simple and ready to use solution above, explaining what you need to replace in your code. Maybe you should read answer before complying for rudeness. On the other hand your code  proves that you have lacks of knowledge in basics.

Comment: Ah.. now I have put my code in edit, that is, apart from explaining it. I have pasted my code there, you will that "simple and ready to use code" I had already used before and I was getting the error. Definitely there is something wrong I am doing and that is why my question is here, but that is not what you are pointing by repeatedly pointing on my basics.

Answer (score 2):

The new error is saying that you don't have the table "DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE" in your database.  From your code that appears to be the Static Field name for the string that contains the name of the table in the database and not the name of the table in the database.

In the code below you need to change "DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE" to the name of the table in the database.

```
String db_sel = "SELECT id as _id, KEY_ROOM_NUMBER" +
",KEY_PATIENT_INITIAL FROM DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE";
```

Try this and see if it will work:

```
String db_sel = "SELECT id as _id, KEY_ROOM_NUMBER" +
",KEY_PATIENT_INITIAL FROM" +  DATABASE_PATIENT_TABLE;
```

As for your original error a SimpleCursorAdapter must contain the field of _id.  The change you made to the SQL Statment that powers the cursor should fix it but you need to make sure you have the right table name in the SQL statement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks George for your help, please kindly have a look in my another snippet of code added. thanks again