# Android sqlite select statement troubles

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am trying to get some data from a sqlite table named Course, with a attribute Name.

I build the table here.

```
private static final String COURSE_ID = "CourseID";
private static final String COURSE_NAME = "Name";
private static final String COURSE_CODE = "CourseCode";
private static final String COURSE_ROWID = "_id";
private static final String COURSE_CREATE =
        "create table " +
"Course" + " ( " + 
COURSE_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
COURSE_ID + " integer not null," 
+ COURSE_NAME + " text not null, " +
COURSE_CODE + " text not null" + ");";
```

I try to select my data with this function.

```
    public Cursor getCourseNames() throws SQLException {
    String[] values = {COURSE_NAME};
    mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return mDb.query("Course",values, COURSE_ROWID + "=" + "Name", null, null, null, null, null); 

}
```

Then in my main class I execute it like this.

```
   public void buildCoursetoChapterList(){

Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getCourseNames();
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, null, null);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

I just want to grab the data and throw in in a list view, any idea what I am doing wrong?
It seems like it is logical `Select from Course WHERE _id = "Name"`;

Oh toot I forgot my error...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: Are you getting an exception somewhere?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I forgot to add it, EDITED!

Comment: it is stating that there is not any column with name `"_id"` check your database definition

Comment: I have this column: private static final String COURSE_ROWID = "_id";

Answer (score 0):

In your database rename `"CourseID"` with `"_id"`

If you want all course names change the return statement like this.

```
return mDb.query("Course",values, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make COURSE_ROWID as "_id"

```
"create table " +
"Course" + " ( " + 
COURSE_ROWID + " AS _id," +
COURSE_ID + " integer not null," 
+ COURSE_NAME + " text not null, " +
COURSE_CODE + " text not null" + ");";
```

This works for row ids that haven't been specified as "integer primary key autoincrement" (all tables have a row id column).

Comment: but my COURSE_ROWID is already declared as "_id"

Comment: see the below links that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236203/illegalargumentexception-column-id-does-not-exist-when-call-to-simplecursora and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573814/simplecursoradapter-is-being-difficult-to-use